# Is it possible to access multiple audio tracks in AVI file in Adobe Premier CS5.5?

Tags: video, audio

Is it possible to access multiple audio tracks in AVI file in Adobe Premier CS5.5?

I see only first track.

**UPDATE**

Please, don't doubt file has multiple audio tracks as I said.

This is the information from MPC-HC:

```
General
Complete name                  : ...
Format                         : AVI
Format/Info                    : Audio Video Interleave
Format profile                 : OpenDML
File size                      : 2.19 GiB
Duration                       : 1h 46mn
Overall bit rate               : 2 934 Kbps
Writing application            : VirtualDubMod 1.5.10.2 (build 2540/release)
Writing library                : VirtualDubMod build 2540/release

Video
ID                             : 0
Format                         : MPEG-4 Visual
Format profile                 : Advanced Simple@L5
Format settings, BVOP          : 1
Format settings, QPel          : No
Format settings, GMC           : No warppoints
Format settings, Matrix        : Default (H.263)
Muxing mode                    : Packed bitstream
Codec ID                       : XVID
Codec ID/Hint                  : XviD
Duration                       : 1h 46mn
Bit rate                       : 2 019 Kbps
Width                          : 720 pixels
Height                         : 304 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 2.35:1
Frame rate                     : 25.000 fps
Color space                    : YUV
Chroma subsampling             : 4:2:0
Bit depth                      : 8 bits
Scan type                      : Progressive
Compression mode               : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)             : 0.369
Stream size                    : 1.50 GiB (69%)
Writing library                : XviD 1.2.0.dev48

Audio #1
ID                             : 1
Format                         : AC-3
Format/Info                    : Audio Coding 3
Mode extension                 : CM (complete main)
Codec ID                       : 2000
Duration                       : 1h 46mn
Bit rate mode                  : Constant
Bit rate                       : 448 Kbps
Channel(s)                     : 6 channels
Channel positions              : Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE
Sampling rate                  : 48.0 KHz
Bit depth                      : 16 bits
Compression mode               : Lossy
Stream size                    : 342 MiB (15%)
Alignment                      : Split accross interleaves
Interleave, duration           : 40 ms (1.00 video frame)
Interleave, preload duration   : 500 ms

Audio #2
ID                             : 2
Format                         : AC-3
Format/Info                    : Audio Coding 3
Mode extension                 : CM (complete main)
Codec ID                       : 2000
Duration                       : 1h 46mn
Bit rate mode                  : Constant
Bit rate                       : 448 Kbps
Channel(s)                     : 6 channels
Channel positions              : Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE
Sampling rate                  : 48.0 KHz
Bit depth                      : 16 bits
Compression mode               : Lossy
Stream size                    : 342 MiB (15%)
Alignment                      : Split accross interleaves
Interleave, duration           : 40 ms (1.00 video frame)
Interleave, preload duration   : 500 ms
```

Comment: Please be more specific about the source file. Are you taking a composite file of audio and video and expecting to break this down to the original audio racks? Do you know if the this file had multiple audio tracks in it before it was rendered to .avi?

Comment: See update please.

Comment: I would think that the one audio track you see is a composite of the two listed in the properties you just posted. Does it sound like everything is in this one track or is it obviously missing something, like voice or music or foley?

Comment: No, I hear exactly first track and nothing more. No mixing of 2 tracks occur. Ok, I see that AP just don't imagine that multiple tracks can exist...

Comment: Hold on, I am no expert in CS5.5. I am just coming at this thinking that you are trying to reverse render the original, and I don't think that is possible but I am not certain. Wait for one of the CS5.5 experts to chime in. Sorry if I wasted your time.

Comment: I can switch these tracks with MPC-HC, so they are definitely separable.

Comment: P.S. These tracks contain different languages.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2801/discussion-between-filzilla-and-dims)

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't count on directly loading the multiple tracks in Premiere Pro CS5.5; usually NLE software is geared towards the video production process, and typically the audio that is captured as part of a footage is a single stream, regardless of the number of channels it contains.

Whereas you seem to be trying to edit a finished product i.e. a ripped movie with multiple language dubs muxed in the AVI

Your best bet is to demux the inaccessible audio stream into a standalone AC3 or multiple WAV files. These files should sync right up with the accessible audio stream and you can group them together, if you want.

The tool to demux AVI is ... [Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/). Load the file in Avidemux. Go to the audio menu. Click on Main track. Set your audio source to Video. In the 2nd drop down, select the additional stream. Click OK. Go back to the audio menu. Select save. Set the extension as per the info shown in Main track dialog. In the case of the file in the question above, it's AC3.